# transition().each() changes after D3 v3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I trying to create subtransitions using `transition.each()`, but the transitions created in the `each` callback does not inherit the transition settings from the parent transition; the following code maintains the 8000 duration under v3, but not under v6.

```js
let dataset = [{
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 50,
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    color: 'blue'
  },
  {
    x: 50,
    y: 100,
    color: 'yellow'
  }
]
let svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200)

let circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("cx", d => d.x)
  .attr("cy", d => d.y)
  .attr("fill", d => d.color)

parent_transition = d3.select({}).transition()
  .duration(8000)


parent_transition.each(() => { // does not inherit duration
  circles.transition()
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => dataset[(i + 1) % 4].x)
    .attr("cy", (d, i) => dataset[(i + 1) % 4].y)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

How should I do the equivalent in v6?

Answer (score 0):

This was a deliberate change made more than 4 years ago, when D3 v4 was released. According to the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#transitions-d3-transition):

> Transitions created this way inherit timing from the closest ancestor element, and thus are synchronized even when the referenced transition has variable timing such as a staggered delay. This method replaces the deeply magical behavior of transition.each in 3.x; **in 4.0, transition.each is identical to selection.each**. (emphasis mine)

That said, it's not exactly clear what's your goal here. One possible solution is using named transitions:

```js
let dataset = [{
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 50,
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    color: 'blue'
  },
  {
    x: 50,
    y: 100,
    color: 'yellow'
  }
]
let svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200)

let circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("cx", d => d.x)
  .attr("cy", d => d.y)
  .attr("fill", d => d.color)

const parent_transition = d3.transition()
  .duration(8000)

circles.transition(parent_transition)
  .attr("cx", (d, i) => dataset[(i + 1) % 4].x)
  .attr("cy", (d, i) => dataset[(i + 1) % 4].y);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Named transition will work perfect for my purposes.